# Python-telegram-bot bypass flood and 429 error using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I follow the price drops on the target site. If there is a price decrease in accordance with the rules I have set, it is recorded in the notificate table. From there, a telegram notification is sent through the code I created in the `pipelines.py` file.
Sometimes the target site discounts too many products and 200 products can come from the notificate table. I'm stuck with telegram's flood protection while sending these.

Things I've tried:

1- `Rotating multiple tokens`

2- `add sleep time`

However, I cannot say that I was successful. I'm still stuck with the flood barrier.

What I want to do here is;
No matter how many notifications come from the Notificate table, queue them and send these notifications in a way that does not exceed 20 messages per second.

How can I do that.

My `pipeline.py` code:

```
def sendnotifications(self, token):
        cursor = self.cnx.cursor()
        req = requests
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM notificate WHERE token= '"+token+"'")
        notifications = cursor.fetchall()
        for notification in notifications:
            print(notification)
            productid = notification[1]
            url = notification[3]
            name = notification[2]
            old = notification[4]
            new = notification[5]
            price_difference = old - new
            percentage = price_difference / old
            percentage_str = str("%.2f" % (percentage * 100))
            

            message = "<b>" + name + "</b>" + "\n\n" + \
                str(old) + " TL >>>> " + \
                str(new) + f" TL - {percentage_str}%" + "\n\n" + \
                url + "\n\n" + \
                

            if str(old) == "1.00" or str(old) == "2.00":
                message = "<b>" + name + "</b>" + "\n\n" + \
                    "<b>" + str(new) + " TL\n\n" + "</b>" + \
                    url + "\n\n" + \
                    
                

            token_list = [
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
                "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
                "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
                "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc",
          

            ]

            TOKEN = token_list[random.randint(0, len(token_list)-1)]


            
            chat_id = "-100xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
            # tel_url = bot.sendMessage(chat_id = chat_id, text = message, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
            
            try:
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id = chat_id, text = message, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
                sleep(0.05)

            except Exception:

                return False
        cursor.close()
        return True
```

Comment: The obvious way seems to be to chunk the updates into batches of 20 and sleep for more than 1 second between them...?

Comment: @thebjorn thank you for your answer. Yes I want to this but how can I make this? if the updates more than 20 (in time) batches of 20. So received 93 updates from mysql batches of 20 (1sec sleep) + 20 (1sec sleep) + 20(1sec sleep) + 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way seems to be to chunk the updates into batches of 20 and sleep for more than 1 second between them:

```
# ...
notifications = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()

for i in range(0, len(notifications), 20):
    chunk = notifications[i:i+20]
    for notification in chunk:
        print(notification)
        # ...
    time.sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: thank you so much. So sorry I'm newbie, Should I add this code after `cursor.close()` ?

Comment: you should close the cursor after you've fetched all records, and before you start processing chunks (since that involves sleeping, and you don't want to keep the cursor open if you don't need it).

Comment: I tried your code and I received 47 items from notification table but can be send only 22.

Comment: I don't know anything about the telegram api, so I'm afraid I can't help you any further. I would suggest reading the error messages and the documentation to figure out what the error is and what the rate-limiting policies are. You could always try smaller chunks and longer sleeps...

Comment: ps: if there is flood-protection issues you might need sleeps inbetween individual notifications also...